# 3.5 mm component video jack -> Ipod female connection?

Tags: ipod, cable, adapter, connector

At my gym the treadmills all have ipod male cables hanging out of them so that you can plug in a video ipod and play a video directly to the screen on the treadmill.

I own a non apple MP4 player is there an adapter that will go from a 3.5mm component video jack to a female ipod connector that will allow me to watch a film on the screen?

Comment: generally device questions are offtopic here.  however, since the adapter needed isn't particularly device-specific, and could conceivably be useful on computers as well, i think this question is ok.

Comment: On the iPod side, are you talking about the 30-pin dock connector? Also, don't you mean *composite* video instead of component?

Comment: Spiff - correct on both, 30-pin dock connector and composite video...